# Possible to duplicate current java stack using JNI

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I am trying to record the arguments passed to a method before it is called using bytecode instrumentation.

Currently while instrumenting using java code I have to first pop all the args into a locals, then push them again twice (once for my method which will record and in this case all primitive types have to be converted to their boxed types, and once for the actual method call).

What I would ideally like to do is just duplicate the entire stack for the num of args pushed for the method call. However the jvm bytecode's dup() instruction only allows duplicating the topmost value of the stack.
Is it possible using JNI to somehow duplicate the entire stack in one go?

Answer (score 1):

No. The stack effectively goes away when the method is compiled. The JVM has no way of compiling native code. So even if you did try to directly manipulate the stack, it would change format (and use registers) on the fly.

You can reasonably easily duplicate the top four slot of the stack (using dup2_x2), but any further and you'll probably need to use local variables.